# how to handle a failure when writing multiple documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to essentially update two (or more) collections sequentially, in a way that allows error(loss of service) tolerance. Because the database or the interface may go down at any time during a write, and the system is writing all the time, I need to be able to resume where I left off without loosing data or duplicating it when resuming.

In the testing I've done, every time I interrupt the process, I end up with duplicate data because I'm updating the progress after I update the record.

According to the documentation, it seems like this can only be achieved using a client-side implementation where I essentially implement a transaction log. The document is updated with what change is about to be made, then I update a collection and after the transaction is done I update the document that the transaction is done.

Is there a pattern for dealing with this issue that doesn't require multiple reads and writes?

Comment: Without multiple reads and writes? Not really. Besides you state yourself that you are writing over multiple collections so that requires at least "two" write operations sans any method of "transactional control". A general approach would be to just write a single "embedded transactional statement" and then process to write to target collections and control the transaction later. So your initial commit is only one write, but ultimately there must be quite a few. But a bit to broad to explain without context